# Oracle SQL grouping elements

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I know this question is kind of trivial but I have difficulties writing the SQL for the example shown below.
As shown in the first table, is the result that i generated and they are ok for analytics,

```
REGION  SUBREGION    SUM
------  ---------    ------
CORP    CORP1       5  
CORP    CORP2       10 
CORP    CORP3       5 
SB      SB1         10 
SB      SB2         10 
MID     null        10 
LARGE   null        20
```

but for summary report i need to display result as shown in the second table. Any clues?

```
REGION  SUM
------  ----
CORP    20
CORP1   5
CORP2   10
CORP3   5
SB      20
SB1     10
SB2     10
MID     10
LARGE   20
```

Comment: What have you tried? How did you generate the first report (as the second will be only a minor change from it).

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your existing GROUP BY to `GROUPING SET`:

```
SELECT
   Coalesce(subregion, region) AS region,
   Sum(column)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(region, subregion)
HAVING Coalesce(subregion, region) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need to aggregate the same table by different fields, but get both back as if it were one field. The solution that comes to mind is a UNION

```
select sum() as sum, REGION as sf from table group by REGION
union ALL
select sum() as sum, SUB_REGION as sf from table group by SUB_REGION;
```

Hope that helps

based on Dan's question below, I add, if you don't want to agg the vals, just take out the sum and group by and do the straight union

```
 select REGION as sf from table 
    union ALL
    select  SUB_REGION as sf from table;
```

EDIT:
One more thought, perhaps when you do the query in the first place, you may want to look into the concept of ROLLUPs as an additional clause on your group bu and agg function, might help solve this in one shot.

Comment: `sum()`?  Are you sure about that?

Comment: @DanBracuk no i'm not sure, but his example says "sum" as the column name, which implied that would be the appropriate agg function to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try using OLAP functions `rollup` and `grouping` like this:

```
select 
  nvl(subregion, region) region, sum("sum")
from  t
group by region, rollup(subregion)
having case when count(*) = 1 then 0 else 1 end = grouping(subregion);
```

In the above,

```
having case when count(*) = 1 then 0 else 1 end = grouping(subregion);
```

The above excludes the rolluped row if there is only one row for that region so that there are no duplicates.

Also, avoid using reserved keywords such as sum or count in your identifiers.

Demo:

```
SQL> with t(REGION ,SUBREGION    ,s) as (
  2  select 'CORP'   , 'CORP1'   , 5  from dual union all
  3  select 'CORP'   , 'CORP2'   , 10 from dual union all
  4  select 'CORP'   , 'CORP3'   , 5  from dual union all
  5  select 'SB'        ,'SB1'          ,10  from dual union all
  6  select 'SB'        ,'SB2'          ,10  from dual union all
  7  select 'MID'       , null   , 10    from dual union all
  8  select 'LARGE'  ,  null   , 20   from dual
  9  )
 10  select
 11    nvl(subregion, region) region, sum(s)
 12  from  t
 13  group by region, rollup(subregion)
 14  having case when count(*) = 1 then 0 else 1 end = grouping(subregion);

REGIO     SUM(S)
----- ----------
SB1           10
SB2           10
SB            20
MID           10
CORP1          5
CORP2         10
CORP3          5
CORP          20
LARGE         20

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the same group by query you're doing, but try using group by ROLLUP:

Something like (untested):

```
select region, subregion, sum(some_column) as sum
from some_table
group by rollup(region, subregion)
order by region, subregion;
```